# ThrowawayController Exception migrating from springframework 2.5.6 to 3.2.8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ant, weblogic

i am migrating springframework 2.5.6 to 3.2.8. on a Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0
replacing

```
 <include name="**/spring-2.5.6.jar"/>
 <include name="**/spring-webmvc-2.5.6.jar"/>
```

for

```
<include name="**/spring/spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-context-support-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-expression-3.2.8.RELEASE"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-jdbc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>               
<include name="**/spring/spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-jdbc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-tx-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-expression-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
```

Compiling the project using ant, I got next error;

```
    weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.throwaway.ThrowawayController
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.throwaway.ThrowawayController
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

But i really don't know from where it comes from, because I don't use this class in the project; I haven't found any reference at all.

Thanks

Comment: Well there must be some reference (indirect maybe) to it. Also you are mixing versions of Spring. You shouldn't include the `spring-dao-2.0.8` dependency as that is, as the version already mentions, for Spring 2.0.8 and nog 3.2.8. It has been replaced with the `spring-orm` jar.

Comment: spring-dao-2.0.8.jar removed, but the problems still persists :-(

Comment: As mentioned the class is referenced somewhere (maybe indirectly). Post the full stacktrace.

Comment: solved after addind: 
spring-expression-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar and
spring-instrument-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar